# What do PA and PU mean in AVR lingo?

Tags: avr

My [Google-fu](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Google-fu) is letting me down today.

What do `PA` and `PU` mean in ATmega88PA and ATmega8-16PU?

If `P` for [PDIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_in-line_package#Variants) what is `A` and `U`, then?

Comment: Details are at the end of each data sheet. There will be a table with the ordering codes for each package type and another table with descriptions of the package type. There will also be detailed drawings of each package, with dimensions. Reading the data sheet is the only way to be sure you get what you want when ordering parts.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the AVR codes mean:

- AU - TQFP
- MU - QFN
- PU - DIP

Comment: +1 - An excellent, and to the point, answer: PU => DIP. Thanks. May I offer also MMH(4) => QFN

Answer (score 5):

I think the confusion here is that ATmega88PA is an actual chip. As you can see from the way it's written, "PA" is not a tag-on package code after a dash but a part of the model number. And yes, the information for the package types and codes is in the datasheet under "ordering information".

So, the ATmega8-16PU is an [ATmega8](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega8.aspx), and the ATmega88PA-* are [ATmega88PA](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega88pa.aspx). I might guess A's are somehow improved (from non-A) devices and P means picopower line.

Comment: yes, that was also the conclusion I came to after researching some more for several hours.

Comment: I found this very useful list of AVR chips with 40 features/parameters: [Parametric Product Table for Atmel AVR microcontrollers](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/param_table.asp?family_id=607&OrderBy=part_no&Direction=ASC). It makes it very easy to see how a particular chip is different from similar chips with the same amount of SRAM/flash/EEPROM, for instance, if one chip is specified for a board and the other is the one that can be purchased from a supplier of ICs. Can you incorporate that link (and perhaps a description) into your answer?

Comment: That link seems to be effectively broken now (redirecting to some generic page).

Comment: Seems Atmel has broken their site all around. Nothing new from a company like that. New links are more readable, though, which of course is nice. I updated the ones in my answer.

Comment: The new link for the *Parametric Product Table* (or rather replacement) is *[Microcontrollers (MCUs) Selector](http://www.atmel.com/v2pfresults.aspx#(actives:!(),data:(area:%27%27,category:%2734864%27,pm:!(),view:list),sc:1))*

Comment: However, the new tool seems wholly inadequate. When I tried it, of the ATmega8s it would only return the very specialised devices ATmega8HVA and ATmega16HVA, "A monitoring and protection circuit for 1-cell and 2-cell Li-ion applications that require high security and authentication", not say a regular [ATmega8](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATMEGA8.aspx), e.g. ATmega8-16PU.

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://www.inforeg.lt/handbooks/Atmel/acrobat/doc0538.pdf) might help, but it's a little outdated and doesn't seem to mention A and U.